# USB bench marking shows faster write speeds after fragmentation? How?

Tags: usb, benchmarking

I am currently benchmarking my 3.0 USB Flash drive both fragmented and defragmented.

My initial setup consisted of Crystal Disk Mark and a flash drive with no files on it.  I recorded the output several times and took an average.

Then, I fragmented the drive using PassMark Fragger and checked the defragmentation level with Defraggler.  For a test with around 80% fragmentation, the write speeds actually got **FASTER**  how could this be?

Comment: Fragmentation means little to nothing on solid state devices like flash memory.  One cell is just as fast to read as others, regardless of how close or far they are from each other. There's some other reason it was faster.  Caching perhaps, differing bus loads when tests were ran, etc.

Comment: If the drive is a SSD, then the drive will *intentionally* fragment the data due to TRIM

Comment: There are many write ups that do suggest that fragmentation affects flash memory.  For example http://www.lagom.nl/misc/flash_fragmentation.html

and

http://blog.condusiv.com/post/2007/06/22/The-Impact-of-Fragmentation-on-Flash-Drives-(iPods-Jump-Drives-etc).aspx